# how to override default value 3 of annotation RetryableTopic in spring kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, boot

I have a requirement where i want to retry infinite times(why infinite times because i am calling 3rd party API from a consumer and that API can give the status as pending and as per 3rd party they hold the transaction for 2 days and if still transaction is pending they fail the transaction after 2 days). I want to retry until i get failure i.e infinite times for me.

i thought to override default value of attempts field of annotation RetryableTopic so that if i don't mention attempts then infinite attempts will be triggered.

I am looking extending RetryableTopicAnnotationProcessor and override method processAnnotation to set max attempts as Interger.Max_Value when we get default value 3.

My question is if i extend RetryableTopicAnnotationProcessor then how do i register that extended class as a default processor for  RetryableTopic annotation ?

Comment: Are you sure you really want to do that? It will create thousands of topics (unless you use a single topic for all retries with a fixed delay). In any case, why can't you just set the property to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` on the annotation?

Comment: I have this requirement for multiple consumers so thought to do at center place. Yes i can set Integer.Max_Value with in annotation also but i also want to know from knowledge point of view  like if i get req to override default behaviour of annotation then how can i register extendable class as default processor ?

Comment: Can't you just make that `@RetryableTopic` as a meta-annotation for your custom one and sent that `attempts` to the `"2147483647"` value?

Comment: `@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RetryableTopic
public @interface customRetry {

    String attempts() default Integer,MAX_VALUE;
}`   I tried doing same but getting compile error "@RetryableTopic is not applicable to annotation Type".

Comment: Meta annotation support is coming in 3.0 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2440 however, full support with aliases will need this too https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2441 I pinged the originator earlier today. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2440#issuecomment-1292125299

Comment: The `RetryableTopicAnnotationProcessor` is not currently overridable. It is tightly bound to the `RetryTopicConfigurationProvider` which in turn is tightly bound to the `KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.